# Unique carts for different users

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to have a unique cart for different users? If I log in as a user and add items to my cart, and then log in as another user, it shows the same items in my cart. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, Commerce carts [exist independently](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/configuration#cartcookieduration) of a Craft user's session.

A workaround would be to write a simple [plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that listens to something like the [onLogin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#userSession-onLogin) event and that plugin would check for the `commerce_cart` cookie and if it exists, nuke it.

That would force a new cart for each new login.